# Compiling ARM with buildroot- how to tell where are the ARM GCC include file

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, buildroot

I am trying to compile buildroot to ARM cortex M4.

i donwloaded the ARM Cross compiler
https://developer.arm.com/open-source/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm/downloads

and configure buildroot using xconfig to use external tool chain with direction to the arm gcc compiler

but i am getting that it search the version.h include in /usr/include

how to i tell gcc in buildroot to search in my installed directory

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This cross compiler from ARM is a bare metal compiler, so it cannot build Linux userspace applications/libraries. Therefore, trying to use this compiler with Buildroot does not make much sense, because the whole point of Buildroot is to build a Linux system, with Linux userspace applications and libraries.

Comment: so i donwloaded codesourcery  and create the bash shell script for the compiler : export HOSTCC=arm-none-eabi-gcc
export HOSTCXX=arm-none-eabi-g++
export BR2_DL_DIR=/home/elia/BuildRootDownloads
export PATH=/usr/local/CodeBench_1802_EABI/bin:/home/elia/uclibc/include:$PATH
export UCLIBC_CONFIG_FILE=/home/elia/buildroot2017_02/buildroot-2017.02.2/package/uclibc/uClibc-ng.config      i am using internal toolchain in the settings, and from what i undestand from this error     /symbol.c:10:25: fatal error: sys/utsname.h: No such file or directory   is that uclibc header cannot be found

Comment: i am trying to compile raspbberyPi3 using buildroot. so i did the following  make raspberrypi3_defconfig  and then make.  i installed the CS toolchain and uclibc and add it to the environment like i mention above. i cannot yet overcome the error of sys/utsname.h : no such file.                                                        btw i tried external toolchain , but there i got different errors. can  you please help?